# Convert nested for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I made for loop code like this:

```
all = []
for sen_list in sen_lists:
    te = []
    for ele in sen_list:
        boolean = ele == "."
        te.append(boolean)
    all.append(te)

sen_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '.', '.'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

upper code works well... but I want to convert list comprehension code.

I try like this:

```
[ele == "." for sen_list in rawdf.TEXT[:10] for ele in sen_list]
```

but this code is doesn't work.

please let me know. thanks.

Comment: Please explain why your attempt did not work

Comment: As far as I can see, your attempt "works": you get the Boolean identification of the periods in a list, one Boolean per character.  Is it because you switched from nested lists to flattened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a *nested* list comprehension. Or, in other words, a list comprehension *of* list comprehensions.

The inner one represents your inner `for` loop. The outer one represents your outer `for` loop.

```
sen_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '.', '.'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]

res = [[ele == "." for ele in sen_list] for sen_list in sen_lists]

# [[False, False, False, False, True, True], [False, False, False, False]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap you boolean logic in [  ] so that `boolean =` knows what it is supposed to equal.

```
boolean = [ele == '.']
```

I don't know the logic to do it all on one line, like you're trying to do at the end of your question.. would be cool though.